# adding 301 redirect to wp site (with existing rules)

Tags: .htaccess

I've been asked to redirect two pages to a different url. It's working except I get a trailing  backslash at the end of the url due to the existing WP rewrite rules. I need to redirect these pages, but leave the WP rules intact for the pages that don't redirect.
Here are the existing WP rules:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I want to add:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

Redirect 301 /*old url* http://*new url*/about.html
Redirect 301 /*old url* http://*new url*.com/tour.html
```

When I do this it redirects to:
new url.com/tour.html/
and the trailing backslash is causing the problem

I am a total .htaccess novice.
Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

This is a case with mod_alias and mod_rewrite interfering with each other because they are both part of the URI-file mapping pipeline, so once mod_alias does its thing (the `Redirect` directives) and flags the URI to be redirected, mod_rewrite then does its thing and rewrites the URI. So at the end of the URI-file mapping pipeline, you've got a 301 redirect but the URI got mangled by mod_rewrite.

You can just stick with mod_rewrite instead and make it so the wordpress rules don't get applied at all. You also need to add your redirects *before* your wordpress rules, so *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?old_url http://new_url/about.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?old_url2 http://new_url/tour.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Jon, this works almost perfectly, but the 2nd rule now redirects to the "about page" not the "tour page." Is it because my 2nd url contains the first one? It's like this: simplegoodeats should go to simplegoodeats.com/about.html and simplegoodeats/tour should go to simplegoodeats.com/tour.html

Comment: Old url 2 is getting redirected to the rule above it. Anyone know why that is. Still stumped here. Thanks!